# Return the name of the country with the highest employment number in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with NumPy and I have the following challenge:

This is my data:

```
import numpy as np

# First 20 countries with employment data
countries = np.array([
    'Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'Angola', 'Argentina',
    'Armenia', 'Australia', 'Austria', 'Azerbaijan', 'Bahamas',
    'Bahrain', 'Bangladesh', 'Barbados', 'Belarus', 'Belgium',
    'Belize', 'Benin', 'Bhutan', 'Bolivia',
    'Bosnia and Herzegovina'
])


# Employment data in 2007 for those 20 countries
employment = np.array([
55.70000076,  51.40000153,  50.5       ,  75.69999695,
58.40000153,  40.09999847,  61.5       ,  57.09999847,
60.90000153,  66.59999847,  60.40000153,  68.09999847,
66.90000153,  53.40000153,  48.59999847,  56.79999924,
71.59999847,  58.40000153,  70.40000153,  41.20000076
])
```

I have to return the name of the country with the highest employment in the given employment data, and the employment in that country.

This is my code:

```
def max_employment(countries, employment):
    max_country = ?????     
    max_value = employment.max()   

    return (max_country, max_value)
```

I got stuck by returning the name of the country with the highest employment number

Comment: np.argmax(employment) will give you the index, then slice the countries using it

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html), which would return the **index** of the maximum value:

```
>>> countries[employment.argmax()]
'Angola'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use argmax method of numpy. argmax return index of maximum item of numpy array.

```
def max_employment(countries, employment):
    max_country = countries.item(employment.argmax())     
    max_value = employment.max()   

    return (max_country, max_value)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `numpy.where` allows you to account for duplicate values, i.e. when more than one country shares the maximum employment. The result will be an array of countries.

```
res = countries[np.where(employment == employment.max())]
```

Since your numeric array consists of rounded percentages, this may well matter.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? This is a likely edge case.

Answer (score -1):

change your max_employment function to this :

```
def max_employment(countries, employment):
    max_value_index = np.argmax(employment)
    max_value = employment[max_value_index]
    max_country = countries[max_value_index]

    return (max_country, max_value)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write:

```
def max_employment(countries, employment):
    max_value = employment.max()  
    max_country = countries[employment.tolist().index(max_value)]
    return (max_country, max_value)
```

You can use `.tolist()` return an array as a list.